# Symfony2/Doctrine - postFlush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

If you saw my previous question, this is kind of linked to it but a new question.  So I have an Entity and I have a listener linked up to this.  In my createAction I create my Object and then persist-flush it to my database.  In my listener, I have set up a postFlush function

```
public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $args)
{
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();

    foreach ($em->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityDeletions() as $entity) {
        if ($entity instanceof AvailabilityAlert) {
            var_dump("TEST");
            $this->api_service->addFlightsAction($entity);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do in this function is get the entity that was just flushed.  I have tried all the different actions of getUnitsOfWork e.g. getScheduledEntityDeletions but for none of them I can get into where the var_dump occurs.

How would I go about getting the flushed entity within this postFlush function?

Answer (score 5):

According to Doctrine2 documentation here : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html you can't call the flushed entities on `PostFlush` event.

However you can split your logic : use the `OnFlush` event to get these entities and then pass it to the `PostFlush` if the flush succeeded.

Comment: How data collected in ``onFlush`` listener can be passed to ``postFlush`` listener?

Comment: Sadly I think this is accurate.  You would have to iterate the UoW on the `OnFlush`, assign what you need, (hope other lifeCycleEvents don't alter it?) pick it up later on the `PostFlush`. Who knew firing off a bit of code after a DB write would be so difficult for an ORM.

Answer (score 1):

To get just persisted to database entity you need not `postFlush` but `postPersist`:

```
public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();
}
```

And don't forget to add next tag to your service:

```
{ name: "doctrine.event_listener",  event: "postPersist" }
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to do something with the entity, and I can only do this once it has been flushed and is in the database.  Is there any way to get the entity in a postFlush?

Comment: in `postPersist` you already have this entity in the database. You also can get `id` from this new record.

Comment: Not if its using a autoinc field for similar for its ID, that won't be in the entity until its flushed.

Comment: In postPersist and postUpdate the entities have NOT been written to the db. The names are wrong as most everything else with Doctrine.

Comment: The comment of lucian is incorrect. The documentation clearly states this. A rollback is still possible at this stage though. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#reference-events-lifecycle-events