# onFlush listener, getting entity Id for a scheduled entity insertions

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I have a listener for **onFlush** event.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $args) {
   $em = $args->getEntityManager();
   $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
   foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
     $id = ...
   }
}
```

I would like to get the Id of the $entity. If I call getId() then return null. Is there any way to finish the flushing inside this listener and get the $entity's Id?

Thank you advance

Comment: If the database is generating the id then there won't be an id until **after** the entity has been inserted.

Comment: The database generates the id, but I don't know that "onFlush" event is before or after database writing operation.

Comment: You should use [postFlush](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postflush)

Comment: I tried postFlush, but I can't find a way how to identify new entities there. Do you know how to decide is it a created/new entity or not?

Comment: we looked for the same a while ago and didn't manage it via a listener, so our services are handling that right now.

Comment: It depends on your logic. Why do you need to know if an entity is a new one?

Comment: I want to write into log table every times when entity created/modified/deleted and I need to know which entity had effected

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589633/symfony2-doctrine-postflush

Comment: @VladimirCvetic there is no solution there, only theorical debutes, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the ID before the SQL INSERT command is executed is impossible but you can access the MySQL table's auto increment value with some tricky ways like this:

```
$classMeta = $em->getClassMetadata($className);
if ($classMeta->rootEntityName !== $className) {
    // if the Entity is inherited, only root entity table may have auto increment ID
    $classMeta = $em->getClassMetadata($classMeta->rootEntityName);
}
$tableName = $classMeta->getTableName();

$conn = $em->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '".$tableName."'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $result['Auto_increment'];
```

Be aware using this:

- this solution is hacky, auto increment value may differ from inserted ID
- your MySQL user must have permission to run this SQL command

Comment: yeah, it's very close to a good solution, and it's works most cases (95%) but as you mentioned before, auto increment may be different fromt the value you've asked from the query. But it's a good point, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem of missing IDs in `onFlush` by creating 2 hooks: onFlush and postFlush. The `onFlush` collects the entities directly (PHP copies pointers, not objects in memory), so after UOW is done with insertions, the IDs appear in the objects.

Therefore

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $objectManager = $eventArgs->getObjectManager();
        $uow = $objectManager->getUnitOfWork();

        $this->dataSyncQueuer->handleEntityUpserts($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions());
...
```

This is how you can store the insertions in `onFlush`:

```
private function promiseUpsertOperation(object $entity): void
    {
        $this->queue[] = function () use ($entity) {
            $this->wallFeedStorage->upsert($entity);
        };
    }
```

This is what you do later in `postFlush`:

```
public function postFlush(PostFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        $queue = $this->queuer->getQueue();

        foreach ($queue as $closure) {
            $closure();
        }
    }
```

Works for me!